# ag-grid-angular npm install -g @ag-grid-community/codemod-runner@31.0.0 is not migrated Upgrading to AG Grid 31

Tags: ag-grid-angular

How to do migration command of ag-grid-angular version 31+ ?

npm install -g @ag-grid-community/codemod-runner@31.0.0
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://artifactory.fis.dev/artifactory/api/npm/fis-npm-dev/@ag-grid-community%2fcodemod-runner - not_found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 '@ag-grid-community/codemod-runner@31.0.0' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in